# html5 on drag change dragging image or icon

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple html like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    .drag-icon{height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: red}
</style>
<script>
    function drag(ev) {
        var drag_icon = document.createElement("div")
        drag_icon.className = "drag-icon"

        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/html", drag_icon);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: #CCC" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
        Hellooww world
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here when I drag the div, while dragging my div is being dragged.
What I want is when I drag the div the dragging div should be changed to `drag_icon`.

How can I do this ?

Comment: What is not working ?

Comment: While dragging the draggin div is not changed to `drag_icon` div..  While dragging I want the dragged div to be changed on `drag_icon` div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `dataTransfer.setDragImage` instead of `setData`,you also need to append the element to DOM, otherwise you wont be able to see element while dragging.
the drag start event should change like this:

```
var drag = function(e,node) {
   var drag_icon = document.createElement("div")
   drag_icon.className = "drag-icon";
   drag_icon.style.position = "absolute";
   drag_icon.style.top = "-100px";
   drag_icon.style.right = "0px";
   document.body.appendChild(drag_icon);
   e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(drag_icon, 0, 0);  
}
```

keep in mind that you should append the element to a part of screen that is invisible for users, so position it out side of the window,first I positioned it far right but it causes body to scroll so hide the overflow-x and that's Ok.

```
body{
  overflow-x:hidden;
}
```

then I changed the position far top, with this approach there is no need to change body style

**There is a working fiddle [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/hsh85/284sgkku/5/)**

for more information and complete walk through take a look at [Setting a custom ghost image when using HTML5 drag and drop](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/custom-drag-image.html)

Comment: @aryan, if it has any problem please let me know.